# Gsuite - Mailed-by and from. How to have a mailed-by as subdomain but the from is the primary domain - in gSuite (Gmail)

Tags: domains, email, email-address, spf, dkim

I want to have my email "from" to be from my primary email (gSuite), adn the mailed-by be from my subdomain (which I have added to my Gsuite account).  Is this possible in GSuite?  I know through different email providers, ex. MailerLite, they allow you to domain alignment to a subdomain, so that the from will be your primary domain but the mailed-by will be the subdomain.  I have attached screenshot from Russel Brunson that he does this, and Neil Patel.  He also does this.
Thanks for your help.
This is my first post.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot#2]